Geometry nodes : How to remove points generated outside of an other object
i would like to know how i can remove the points generated outside of the sphere (which is a separate object).
I tried to use the distance attribute but i didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance :)

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? OneDrive requires logging...

I added the .blend to the post :)

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
NB: In the following GN graphs, dark pink nodes are just to simplify the view by removing instances with negative X coordinates. These are not part of the solution to remove outside points, in dark blue background.

1. The geometry of the object defining "inside" versus "outside" is recovered through an Object Info node with Transform Space set to Relative.
2. Per point, a ray is cast outwards from its Position. To do so, the Ray Direction is also set to the point Position because the origin of the object carrying the GeometryNodes modifier is (0,0,0) in the modifier frame of reference. Consequently, there is not need to subtract it from the point Position.
3. For inside points, the Raycast node returns Is Hit at True. This value is used as the selection mask input in the Instance on Points node.

This figure illustrates how to keep outside points instead.

Super merci ! :)

j'ai une nouvelle question, plus complexe je pense, qui porte sur le même fichier. Est-il possible de distribuer les points en fonction du matériaux de l'objet "Toile cosmique" ? Merci d'avance.
